# Grey Shadow on Wordpress menu

Tags: html, wordpress, css

Good morning everyone!

I'm creating a website using a Wordpress theme and my Menus have a grey shadow that I cannot remove.
[Grey shadow on menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJEsM.png)

The same issue happens when I place the mouse in the other "categories".

I already looked into google and tried to change the custom CSS to the following:

```
    #menu-barra-superior.nav.navbar-nav {   
       background-color: #B40404;   
       text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {   
       color: #FFBF00;   
       text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .dropdown-menu > li > a {   
       color: #FFBF00;  
       text-shadow: none !important;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {   
       color: #FFBF00;   
       text-shadow: none !important;
    }
```

(I added the `text-shadow: none !important`), but this doesn't seem to work.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it were still morning *here* I'm not sure how I would be getting through the rest of the day. Anyway, it looks like you need to be investigating `box-shadow` and not `text-shadow`.

Comment: A great way of determining what properties are causing weird effects is to right-click on an element, select "inspect element" and then click into the "computed" tab. This feature is available in Firefox, Chrome, Edge and probably others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
box-shadow: none;
```

Instead of text-shadow

```
menu-barra-superior.nav.navbar-nav { 
  background-color: #B40404;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #FFBF00;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #FFBF00;
  box-shadow: none !important;

}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a {
  color: #FFBF00;
  box-shadow: none !important;

}
```